# Linking one feature column to another feature column

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I'm new to TensorFlow and am trying to perform binary classification on my dataset. Essentially, I'm trying to predict whether an item is "attractive" or "not attractive".

I've simplified my training set to look something like that:

```
lamp;      20cm;  description: lightbulb, switch; attractive 
lightbulb; 3cm;   description: filament;          attractive 
switch;    1cm;   description: switch;            not attractive
filament;  0.5cm; description: -;                 attractive
```

Explanation of features:

- 1st column is the name of the item
- 2nd column is the width of item
- 3rd column is a list of text related to the item. Note here that this list can be `NULL` or have >0 items. Note also that each of the items in the list **will appear exactly once in the 1st column of one of the rows** in the dataset.

And the 4th column shows the classification of the training data.

---

From what I've read online, if I'm not mistaken, the above data cannot be used just like that - it needs to be converted into a format readable by TensorFlow.

Note: I do not want to do any text classification since the prediction should be based on its attribute (width) and its relation with other items.

My attempt at making the training set usable(?) - by encoding each of the items with an item ID and then using an array to represent the relations:

```
1; 20;  [2, 3]; 1 
2; 3;   [4];    1 
3; 1;   [3];    0
4; 0.5; [];     1
```

Test set:

```
5; 12;  [2, 2]; ?
```

I'm assuming there's no need to create a separate file with the mapping of ID to item names since I'd previously mentioned that the item name itself is assumed to have no bearing on the result?

Questions:

- If the above format is put into a CSV file, is that alright?
- Is there any way to "link" the 3rd column to the 1st? So that TensorFlow knows that the 3rd column is actually an array of keys into the first.
- Any available resources/tutorials that might help? I've already gone through the Getting Started guide with the Iris flowers example (but their features are all decimals - with no user-specified relations to other features).

Answer (score 1):

Re 1., TF supports csv just fine

For 2 and 3, you should look at [the documentation for tf feature columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns).